# Запуск Perl-скрипта в Windows

Tags: perl

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда надо поместить jpegtran, что скрипт [jpegrescan](http://rghost.ru/37608257) заработал?

И еще как можно конвертировать скрипт в EXE, интересую только бесплатные решения.

Answer (score 1):

В любую папку переменной окружения `PATH` при желании можно и свою туда  дописать. Можно положить в `C:\Windows\` (или где операционка установлена) и без дописываний заработает.

Бесплатный упаковщик скриптов в exe: [Citrus Perl](http://www.cava.co.uk/citrusperl/)

Comment: На счет jpegtran, а можно сделать по другому?

Можно ли сделать, чтобы я сам указывал путь к jpegtran?

perl.exe jpegrescan.pl "путь jpegtran.exe"

На счет "компиляции" спасибо, такой вопрос, а как можно узнать какие модули использует perl-скрипт? тут как бы получается цепочка, одни модули использую другие и т.д., вот как мне получить список этих всех модулей?